# Sqlite3 async quieres waits for heavy API calls to finish in order to execute

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, asynchronous, sqlalchemy

I've tried every LLM out there to figure this out but I couldn't. I have a Flask app which is an API, Most API calls takes more than 10 seconds. The app as a whole is fully async. I use an sqlite file DB with SqlAlchemy to manage API keys I have. Which won't be more than 100 api keys at most. The issue is that SQL quiries take more than 10 seconds to execute if i'm doing other heavy API calls. Although without any API call the response usually takes less than 100ms. I tried to use async, sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio, but still the same issue.

I'm gonna explain the code structure in here:

## (root)/database/db.py

```
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession, async_sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import asyncio
from sqlalchemy.pool import QueuePool

engine = create_async_engine('sqlite+aiosqlite:///main.sqlite3')

def async_session():
 session_factory = async_sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession, future=True )
 return session_factory()

db = SQLAlchemy(session_options={"class_": AsyncSession})
```

## (root)/database/actions.py

```
from database.db import db, async_session
from database.models import ApiKey
from sqlalchemy import select

# A function to get a customer using thier API key.
async def get_customer(api_key):
    async with async_session() as session:
        async with session.begin():
            result = await session.execute(select(ApiKey).where(ApiKey.api_key == api_key))
            key = result.scalars().first()
            if key:
                return {'id': key.id, 'api_key': key.api_key, 'owner_name': key.owner_name}
            else:
                return None

# A function to get all customers ( for admin usage )
async def get_all_customers():
    async with async_session() as session:
        async with session.begin():
            result = await session.execute(select(ApiKey))
            return result.scalars().all()
```

## (root)/app.py

```
from database.actions import get_all_customers,get_customer
from database.db import db, engine
import asyncio

app = Flask(app_name)
db.init_app(app)

# Flask route to get a customer
u/app.route('/api/customers', methods=['GET'])
async def customer_get():
    api_key = request.args.get('api-key')

    try:
        if api_key:
            result = await get_customer(api_key)
            if result:
                return jsonify(result)
            else:
                return {}
        else:
        result = await get_all_customers()
        if result:
            return jsonify(result)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

# Flask route that conduct requests/io and take about 10 to 20 seconds to complete.
u/app.route('/api/call', methods=['GET'])
async def call():
    api_key = request.args.get('api-key')

    try:
        if api_key:
            result = await heavy_call(api_key)
            if result:
                return jsonify(result)
            else:
                return {}
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Now i'm pretty sure i'm doing something wrong in here. I could really use your help guys thanks!

Tried to make async DB calls and make it quick even if heavy proccessing is in the back. But it turns out that it waits for other calls to finish in order to execute.

Comment: If `heavy_call` does too much synchronously in the same thread, other asynchronous operations in the thread are slowed down.

Comment: heavy_call is a IO bound task or CPU bound task? if this is CPU bound task, async doesn't resolve your problem